# Request Payload issue with SAPUI5 UploadCollection

Tags: parameters, request, sapui5, payload

I am using SAPUI5 UploadCollection for multiple and instant upload functionality.

and I am using parameters like this

```
            <parameters>
                <UploadCollectionParameter name="Nbr" value="12" />
            </parameters>
            <headerParameters>
                <UploadCollectionParameter name="Nbr" value="12" />
            </headerParameters>
```

But when i look into Developer tools of the Chrome browser Network tab,I am not getting Request Payload.

The following code i am using.

```
<UploadCollection
                id="UploadCollection"
                maximumFilenameLength="55"
                maximumFileSize="10"
                multiple="false"
                showSeparators="All"
                change="onChange"
                fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed"
                selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
                typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch"
                uploadComplete="onUploadComplete"
                beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts"
                uploadTerminated="onUploadTerminated"
                items="{MeterTicketsModel>/returnData}"

                mode="MultiSelect">

                <toolbar>
                    <OverflowToolbar id="myId" >
                        <Title id="attachmentTitle"/>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Button id="downloadButton" text="Download" press="onDownloadItem" enabled="false" type="Transparent"></Button>
                        <Button id="versionButton" text="Upload a new version" press="onVersion" enabled="false" type="Transparent"></Button>
                        <UploadCollectionToolbarPlaceholder></UploadCollectionToolbarPlaceholder>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
                </toolbar>
                <items>
                    <UploadCollectionItem
                        documentId="{documentId}"
                        fileName="{MeterTicketsModel>fileName}"
                        mimeType="{mimeType}"
                        thumbnailUrl="{thumbnailUrl}"
                        url="{url}"
                        enableEdit="false"
                        enableDelete="false"
                        visibleDelete="false"
                        visibleEdit="false"
                        attributes="{path : 'attributes', templateShareable : 'true'}"
                        statuses="{path : 'statuses', templateShareable : 'true'}"
                        selected="{selected}">
                        <attributes>
                            <ObjectAttribute
                                title="{title}"
                                text="{parts : ['text', 'type'], formatter : '.formatAttribute'}"
                                active="{active}"/>
                        </attributes>
                        <statuses>
                            <ObjectStatus
                                title="{title}"
                                text="{text}"
                                state="{state}"
                                icon="{icon}"
                                iconDensityAware="{iconDensityAware}"
                                textDirection="{textDirection}"/>
                        </statuses>
                    </UploadCollectionItem>
                </items>
                <parameters>
                    <UploadCollectionParameter name="Nbr" value="12" />
                </parameters>
                <headerParameters>
                    <UploadCollectionParameter name="Nbr" value="12" />
                </headerParameters>
            </UploadCollection>
```

Even though I have added params in the controller, I am not getting Request Payload in the console.
The following code I am using in beforeUploadStarts event.

```
onBeforeUploadStarts: function(oEvent) {
    var oFileUploader = this.byId("UploadCollection");
            var sUrl = "some url";
            oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(sUrl);
            var NbrParam = new sap.m.UploadCollectionParameter({
            name : "xyz",
            value : 5
            });

   oEvent.getParameters().addHeaderParameter(NbrParam );
   oFileUploader.addParameter(NbrParam );
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in the controller

```
onFileUploadChange: function (oEvent) {
                var oUploadCollection = oEvent.getSource();
                // Header Token
                var oCustomerHeaderToken = new UploadCollectionParameter({
                    name: "x-csrf-token",
                    value: "securityTokenFromModel"
                });
                oUploadCollection.addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeaderToken);
            },
```

And

```
onBeforeUploadStarts: function (oEvent) {
                var oCustomerHeader = new sap.m.UploadCollectionParameter({
                    name: "slug",
                    value: oEvent.getParameter("fileName")
                });
                oEvent.getParameters().addHeaderParameter(oCustomerHeader);
            },
```

I had the same issue, but the above corrections worked for me. You will not still see the request payload in the console, but my backend ABAP class was receiving the file content.